# Как ограничить размеры header-a, который содержит больше элементов, чем его ширина

Tags: html, css, overflow

Имеется header, в котором внутри есть левая и правая части (выделены красным), внутри правой части есть блок (выделен зеленым). Внутри зеленого блока содержится больше контента, чем ширина header-a. Ограничение overflow: hidden зеленого блока не дает результатов, правый блок просто растягивается из-за него, при том, что у него задана максимальная ширина (или просто ширина, было испробовано и так, и так). Дает результат ограничение правого красного блока overflow: hidden, но при этом обрезается значок на иконке со звуком, и в адаптиве потом обрезается селект с выбором языка. Если задать overflow-x: hidden и overflow-y: visible, значок так и обрезается, а при открытии селекта в адаптиве появляется скролл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не задавать правой части overflow: hidden, то получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если задать, то вот так (иконка обрезается):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно ограничить ширину, не обрезая при этом остальные элементы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: задай максимальную ширину зеленого блока, возможно, добавить ему обертку и обертке задавать все свойства